# PHP: Get specific links with preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, expression

i want to extract specific links from a website.

The links look like that:

```
<a href="1494761,offer-mercedes-used.html">
```

The links are always the same - except the brandname (mercedes in this case).

This works fine so far but only delivers the first part of the link:

`preg_match_all('/((\d{7}),offer-)/s',$inhalt,$results);`

And this delivers the first link with the whole website :(

`preg_match_all('/((\d{7}).*html)/s',$inhalt,$results);`

Any ideas?

Note that i use preg_match_all() and not preg_match().

Thanks,
Chama

Answer (score 1):

While `.*?` would do (= less greedy), in both cases you should specify a more precise pattern.

Here `[\w.-]+` would do. But `[^">]+` might also be feasible, if the HTML source is consistent (or you specifically wish to ignore other variations).

```
preg_match_all('/((\d{7}),offer-[\w.-])/s',$inhalt,$results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse xml/html with regex generally isn't a good idea, but if you're sure it will always be formatted well, this should return any links in the content.

```
/<a href="([^">]+)">/
```

This will more closely match only the example pattern you gave, but not sure what variations you might have

```
/<a href="([0-9]{7},offer-[a-z]+-used\.html)">/
// [7 numbers],offer-[at least one letter]-used.html
```